# What is the proper way to get names, phone numbers and postal addresses from Contacts in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to better understand the ContactsContracts right now but I'm a little confused.

There is a way to query the ContentResolver for a Cursor object, but I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly.

Currently I'm querying with little to no arguments:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

cursor = contactResolver.query(
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
```

Then I try to get StructuredPostals, display names and phone numbers, but it doesn't quite work out.

```
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    String pobox = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
    String street = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
    String city = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
    String state = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
    String postcode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
    String country = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
    String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));
```

How can I fix my query so that I only get contacts with addresses and phone numbers? Thanks for any help!